# Raspberry PI 3B+ won't connect to smartphone Wi-Fi hotspot if it's "Shared wifi" instead of 4G+

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+, hotspot

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 and a Raspberry PI 3B+.

- The PI can connect to a normal Wi-Fi without any problems.
- The PI can connect to my S8's hotspot if internet is from 4G(+)
- The PI CAN NOT CONNECT to my S8's hotspot if internet is from Wifi to my S8 itself (so in other words, if the wifi of my S8 is enabled). On the desktop, I can find the name of my hotspot, but if I click on it and fill in the password, it doesn't do anything and the wifi status remains disconnected...

Does anyone know what the cause of this problem is? Does a Raspberry PI 3B+ not support a hotspot if the hotspot uses "share wifi" or something like that?

Comment: Your RasPi can connect to other hotspots so it seems not to be a problem of the RasPi. Can other devices connect to the S8 hotspot in "shared wifi" mode?

Comment: if the phone has a wifi connection to some local router, then why do you need to connect to this router through the phone? the pi would have the ability to access the same wifi router would it not? I also think that if a phone is acting as a hotspot, it will not be also connected as a wifi client - of course, different phones have different abilities in this regard

Answer (score -1):

By default country for WLAN channels set to US and it forbid channels 12 and 13, Phone may has WIFI AP on this channels. Set WLAN country to correspondent to real (or just not North America) by using `sudo raspi-config` -> `Localisation`

Comment: OP say " On the desktop, I can find the name of my hotspot", so OP can see the channel that the hotspot uses! So a mismatched country setting is unlikely!